# How to check if all values in a column are equal to some value in numpy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

i have defined a matrix m , i wish to return TRUE if there is any column which has all its elements as 1, for example :

```
m = [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

i have tried various approaches but they all seem to return True in all cases(since there are multiple columns with all elements as 0)

Comment: What approaches have you tried?

Comment: `m.all(axis=0).any()`

Comment: @PedroFracassi 1)i converted the 2d matrix , 2) used np.unique ....

Comment: or `np.array(m).all(axis=0).any()` if m is a list of list

Comment: @Psidom this return true even for a matrix having every element as 0 , thanks tho

Comment: @sensualbumfuzzle I don't think so. Can you double check? I am assuming `m` is a numpy array / matrix.

Comment: `(m == 1).all(axis=0).any()`

Comment: @Psidom nevermind , i made a typo , it works , thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

I agree with ansev's response. You gave us a list of lists. I prefer numpy for these kind of exercises.

```
import numpy as np
m = [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

np.array(m).all(axis=0).any()
```

Output

```
True
```